# How do you solve HttpSession loading issue?

Tags: mysql, jsp, session, servlets, httpsession

My question is: is there a way to fix the session loading problem? I am just looking for a general direction. 
I am pretty new to servlet JSP, my situation is: when the user input a value in My JSP page "A.jsp",  the JSP page will go to the servlet "B.java", "B.java" gets the value from "A.jsp", then go to MySQL, find the related data, the HttpSession will then setAttribute, and forward the data back to the "A.jsp" page(getRequestDispatcher). Unfortunately, after a few inputs in the "A.jsp" page, the servlet will stop responding, and the loading issue occurs(the data stopped showing on my screen after my input). I suspect that this might be a session loading problem. 
Is there a way to fix this issue? Should I look for other ways to do this because the HttpSession may not be the way if I want to have a quick response every time?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead.